# Misconception in Compiler's function

Tags: c++, c

I have studied many articles to understand whether *Compiler* generates **Object Code** or **Assembly Code** and there is conflict, even in stack overflow. Some says *Compiler* generates **Object Code** while other says *Compiler* generates **Assembly Code** which is then converted to **Object Code** by *Assembler*. Both answers has up-votes. Is there any clarification or justification for this.

Comment: There is no correct answer as different compilers do this differently.

Comment: Yes there is. A compiler is a general term for something that takes a thing in a source language and produces something in a target language. Both source and target can generally be anything.

Comment: In general, a compiler converts one language to another.

Comment: Refer to authoritative links, whether provided in SO answers or those you find elsewhere. SO is not authoritative by definition.

Comment: Some compilers can do both.  That is, they can compile a source language to either assembly code or machine code, or even to both in the same run.

Comment: with exam point of view, compiler generated code is ?. Object code or Assembly code. I guess both.

Comment: nicomp, will you please suggest some links

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront Original C++ compiler, compiled C++ to C  Also 2 mins with Google will get you the definition of a Compiler.

Comment: Not peer-reviewed but published by a professor who teaches graduate-level compiler theory at a nationally accredited college: https://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node3.html , also here is a book from one of courses I took in grad school co-written by one of the biggest names in compilers:  https://books.google.com/books/about/Compilers.html?id=dIU_AQAAIAAJ

Comment: And then you'll reach the rather tautologous but alas not particularly helpful conclusion that "source code -> compiler -> compiled code". The latter is said to be runnable in a "target" environment.

Comment: @nicomp Just because some professor said something in an introductory course doesn't make it correct or "authoritative". The widely used definition for a compiler is something that translates between two programming languages, not just into machine language as claimed by that link.

Comment: In general, a "translator" is a program which takes a source program in a "source" language and generates an equivalent program in a different "target" language. A "compiler" is a translator which translates a source program in a higher level language to an equivalent program in a lower level language. The target language can be the machine language of a real processor, but quite often, the target language is assembly language or byte code.

Comment: as for as I understood, it depends on the compiler. Some compiler generate object code, some Assembly code and some can generate both. While generating machine code is the responsibility of Linker.

Comment: @interjay what's your point? Are you simply looking for an argument?

Comment: @nicomp Huh? I just said that wasn't a good link to post because its definition for compiler isn't the usual one (and contradicts the definition given in the dragon book). No need to be so combative about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, the compiler has to somehow produce object files with the code that will end up in the application, and the linker combines the code from object files and libraries (which are just collections of object files) to produce the application. So it's correct to say that the compiler produces object files and the linker combines them.

On the other hand, there are various ways that the compiler can produce the object files. One way is to directly generate object files. Another way is to generate assembler code and run the assembler to produce the object files. That introduces some flexibility, because the compiler doesn't have to know the details of how object files are laid out; the assembler does that. Yet another way is to generate C code and run the C compiler (which could, in turn generate assembler code and run the assembler) on that to produce object files. That's how cfront worked back in the olden days of C++. It's also how some modern compiler front-ends work. For example, Edison Design Group sells a C++ front-end that vendors can hook up to their own back-end for code generation. They also provide a version that generates C code, for use during compiler development when the back-end isn't yet working. Typically in these cases, the compiler will have a switch to keep the C or assembler file around, so you can examine that to see what's going on.